# Datetimepicker did not work on element that append form javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

I have one input date, this input append from js like this

```
    var inputdate = '<input type="text" name="date[]" class="form-control date" placeholder="Input date"';
    $("form").append(inputdate);
```

And the html code is like this :

```
    <form method="POST">
       ...
    </form>
```

Initialize datetimepicker

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

The input element append succesfully and the other form that have input date work with datetimepicker.
But the element that append from js is not showing datetimepicker, is there any mistakes?

Comment: For the newly added element you need to initialize the plugin again

Comment: `var $inputdate = '<input type="text" name="date[]" class="form-control date" placeholder="Input date"';
 $("form").append($inputdate);
 $inputdate.datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
 });`

Comment: So, inside function that have append html, the plugin should initialize again?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: it's showing datetimepicker, but when clicked the output is like this : yyyy-37-Fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed one thing here.

```
var inputdate = '<input type="text" name="date[]" class="form-control date" placeholder="Input date"';
```

It should have `>` at the end of string.

The initialization code should be **Re**executed after we append `inputDate` into `$('form')`.

So the code should be:

```
var inputdate = '<input type="text" name="date[]" class="form-control date" placeholder="Input date">';

$("form").append(inputdate);

$('.date').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'});
```